# How to pass the session/cookie/login in one project to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a mvc project and webforms project, I use iframe to embed the webforms in the mvc. How can I get the login information of the mvc to automatically login also the webforms?

Answer (score 0):

The Authentication for both of the project must be the same.

Example:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" name="YourAuthenticationName" enableCrossAppRedirects ="true" domain="projectdomain.com" requireSSL="false" />
</authentication>
```

And both must have a machineKey

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="A225194E99BCCB0F6B92BC9D82F12C2907BD07CF069BC8B4" validationKey="6FA5B7DB89076816248243B8FD7336CCA360DAF8" />
```